# Evaluate dynamically user-added If-Statements

Tags: javascript, swift

How can I achieve that users can add multiply custom if-statements?

For example let's say there is a given variable called x with a given value of let's say 8.
The user sees that x = 8 and has a button to add an if-statement. He clicks the button and can insert the condition which triggers an event (let's say it prints "Hello World"). So he enters "x < 100" into the field which is true. Therefore "Hello World" is printed.
After clicking the button once again, he is able to add an other condition, let's say "x < 7" which is also true. Because both conditions are true, "Hello World" is still printed.
I think you got the point of my questions, even though I lack the vocabulary.
So how could I manage to let user add an undefined amount of conditions which will be checked before "Hello World" is printed?
The only solution I know is to limit the possible amount of conditions and check each one if it is empty / what the conditions says.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your question about Swift or about JavaScript?

Comment: Somewhere, x stopped being 8? :)

Comment: Sorry.. forgot to mention; it is more about the logic behind this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you want to build an entire language you have to get clear on what exact operations you are going to allow here.

For example the operation of `<` and `>` and `==`, basically all comparison operations (`<=` and `>=` as well) can be implemented via the following:

```
/* your X variable, might be var if you desire to change */
let x = 12

/* the array of conditions the user entered */
var conditions : [(((Int, Int) -> Bool), Int)] = []

/* some user input - read as e.g. "x > 2"*/
conditions.append((<, 100))
conditions.append((>, 2))
conditions.append((==, 12))

/* you evaluate all conditions in the following way */
let eval = conditions.map { $0(x, $1) }
let allTrue = !eval.contains(false)
/* allTrue would be true in this case because 12 < 100 && 12 > 2 && 12 == 12 */
```

Your "hard" job is it now to interpret the user input as some `condition`. But that is not too difficult, you simply need a mapping of the text input of `"<"` to the actual operator `<`.

You can adjust the above code to take care of `Double` instead of `Int` easily if you fell like you need that. **But you have to aware of floating point inaccuracy and the problem that arise when checking for equality** (thanks to @dfri for pointing this out).

A little bit more difficult part comes in regards to combining the conditions with `or` instead of `and` what above code does and what you currently describe in your question.

*Just because I like closures:* The following is the entire input reading and parsing:

```
func getOperator(str: String) -> ((Int, Int) -> Bool)? {
    switch str {
    case "<":
        return (<)
    case ">":
        return (>)
    case "==":
        return (==)
    case "<=":
        return (<=)
    case ">=":
        return (>=)
    default:
        return nil
    }
}

func parseUserInput(str:String) -> (((Int, Int) -> Bool), Int) {
    var input = str as NSString
    input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    //let variable = input.substringToIndex(1) // in case you want more than one variable, but that will have to change the entire setup a bit
    // this has to be this "ugly" to incorporate both 1 char and 2 char long operators
    let operato = input.substringFromIndex(1).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet())
    let number = input.substringFromIndex(operato.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding) + 1)

    if let number = Int(number), op = getOperator(operato) {
        return (op, number)
    }

    return ((<, 999999)) // need some error handling here
}

conditions.append(parseUserInput("x > 123"))
```

Instead of resolving the operator using a function you can even use a plain old dictionary mapping from `">"` to `(>)` etc.

Comment: Closures, this was neat!

Comment: @dfri I <3 closures :)

Comment: I'm learning from closure guys like you :) Out of curiosity, how would you treat the case of floating point comparison with a tolerance, using the same approach as you have done above?

Comment: @dfri well, that is going to be difficult, but if the user desires he simply can place a `> 11.999999` and `< 12.00001` in. My above example would simply rely on the precision of the language determining of two doubles are equal -> `12.0000000000000001 == 12.0 -> true`

Comment: how about `let eval = conditions.map { ($0(x, $1) || $0(x-MY_TOL, $1) || $0(x+MY_TOL, $1)) } ` for some tolerance `MY_TOL`? Shouldn't mess up `<` or `>`, but allow for tolerance on `==` check.

Comment: @dfri hmm, that does no longer look as pretty. I will certainly include a "caution" statement when moving to floating point, but will not yet include any special handling for it.

Comment: I agree it does strip the elegance of the previous expression. Nice addition with the parsing!

Comment: @user1658080 well, you have not chosen an easy topic for a beginner ;)

Comment: @user1658080 Luckily you have three answers raging from _(simple, not so neat) --> (somewhat complicated, very elegant)_. If you have the time, I think it could be a valuable exercise to cover all three answers, as they all use different approaches to solve the same problem. Start with my basic imperative `struct` answer, thereafter proceed to the neater `enum` solution of R Menke, and finally, try to get a grip around luk2302 really elegant solution above. Hopefully it will be easier to grip what's happening if you traverse through incrementally more advanced solutions to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

First you need a way to switch between operators. A very simple `enum` is perfect for this. Just add all the operators you want to use.

```
enum Operator : String {

    case biggerThan = ">"
    case smallerThan = "<"
    case equal = "=="

    init?(string:String) {
        switch string {
        case ">" :
            self = .biggerThan
        case "<" :
            self = .smallerThan
        case "==" :
            self = .equal
        default :
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Each time a user clicks a button and inserts a condition, a corresponding `Condition` value will be created.

```
struct Condition {
    var value: Int
    var operation: Operator
}
```

This function returns a `Bool` depending on `x`, the `inputValue` and the chosen `operator`.

```
func checkCondition(x: Int, condition: Condition) -> Bool {
    switch condition.operation {
    case .biggerThan :
        return condition.value > x
    case .smallerThan :
        return condition.value < x
    case .equal :
        return condition.value == x
    }
}
```

This does the same but for a whole bunch of conditions. Here you can implement more logic. If all need to be true for example add : `if !result { return false }`.

```
func checkAllConditions(x:Int, conditions: [Condition]) {
    for condition in conditions {
        let result = checkCondition(x, condition: condition)
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is store conditions in an array as the user creates them

```
func userCondition(operation:String, input:String) -> Condition? {

    guard let op = Operator(string: operation) else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let doubleValue = Double(input) else {
        return nil
    }

    return Condition(value: Int(doubleValue), operation: op)
}

let conditionA = userCondition("<", input: "10")! // use if let instead of !
let conditionB = userCondition(">", input: "10")! // use if let instead of !
let conditionC = userCondition("==", input: "23")! // use if let instead of !

var x : Int = 23

checkAllConditions(x, conditions: [conditionA,conditionB,conditionC])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct MyConditions {
    let myEps: Double = 0.001
    var x: Double
    var lessThan = [Double]()
    var equalTo = [Double]()
    var greaterThan = [Double]()

    init(x: Double) {
        self.x = x
    }

    mutating func addConstraint(operand: Double, op: String) {
        if op == "<" {
            lessThan.append(operand)
        }
        else if op == "==" {
            equalTo.append(operand)
        }
        else if op == ">" {
            greaterThan.append(operand)
        }
    }

    func checkConstraints() -> Bool {
        for op in lessThan {
            if !(x < op) {
                return false
            }
        }
        for op in equalTo {
            if !(x - myEps < op && x + myEps > op) {
                return false
            }
        }
        for op in greaterThan {
            if !(x > op) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
func feasibleHelloWorld(x: MyConditions) {
    if x.checkConstraints() {
        print("Hello world!")
    }
}

var x = MyConditions(x: 8)
x.addConstraint(100, op: "<")
x.checkConstraints() // true
feasibleHelloWorld(x) // Hello world!

x.addConstraint(8, op: "==")
x.checkConstraints() // true
feasibleHelloWorld(x) // Hello world!

x.addConstraint(7, op: "<")
x.checkConstraints() // false
feasibleHelloWorld(x) // ... nothing
```