# When to return a function from another function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

What it the most common situation where you would want to return a function from a function in Swift?

In the code below I'm returning a function but I don't really see the purpose since the function I'm returning is inside the function who is returning it. The reason I'm confused is because we could accomplish the same thing with just one function.

```
func person () -> ((String, Int) -> String) {

  func info(name: String, age: Int) -> (String) {
    return "\(name) is \(age) old"
  }

  return info
}


let nathan = person()
nathan("Nathan", 3)

print(nathan("Nathan", 3))
```

Can someone point out common situations where you would want to return a function and probably illustrate it with a better example?

I want to understand this since this is fundamental for programming in general not just Swift (I think).

Comment: This is a functional programming concept, not necessarily a fundamental for programming. You should read about Functional Programming and the `currying` concept. See this link for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying One of the advantage is that each function only takes in 1 argument.

Comment: @LaurentRivard note that currying will potentially be removed from swift: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md

Comment: Take a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34566757/2442804) for an example of a usage of functions closures as actual returned / used object

Comment: @luk2302 good point! Although the question is tagged with `swift` and `ios`, it seems to be more of a functional programming question. @fs_tigre: Read the article that luk2302 posted, it shows a good example of when you would want to return a function and more importantly what Apple engineers think about some of those concepts for an iOS app.

Comment: @LaurentRivard I agree, currying is a core concept of haskell for example, just wanted to note that it is mostly unused and potentially removed in swift in the future.

Comment: Another interesting article about currying: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introduction-to-function-currying-in-swift

Comment: @luk2302: Currying isn't being removed. The `func add(a: Int)(b: Int) -> Int` syntax will no longer be valid. But you can still write curried functions using `func add(a: Int) -> Int -> Int`.

Comment: @RomanSausarnes yes, but that is just a general closure, there will be no longer a special way of writing a curried function - it will look similar to the regular one.

Comment: @luk2302 that's true, the syntactic sugar is being taken away, but they are still curried functions, only sugar-free :)

Answer (score 7):

A classic example would be in a calculator program, e.g.:

```
func operatorForString(str: String) -> ((Float, Float) -> Float)? {
    if str == "+" {
        return (+) // brackets required to clarify that we mean the function
    } else if str == "-" {
        return (-)
    } else if str == "*" {
        return (*)
    } else if str == "/" {
        return (/)
    } else if str == "**" {
        return pow // No brackets required here
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

if let op = operatorForString("-") {
    let result = op(1, 2) // -1
}
```

It's rather contrived, but it illustrates the principle simply...

As an "exercise to the reader" try to do it as a `Dictionary` lookup, rather than repeated `if`s :)